# Korzah Query Rendring Issue

Tags: query-builder, easyquery

I am working in Korzah easy query 3.7. I am trying to create a query that uses the maximum attribute of date time. I execute it and it provides me with the desired result but the problem arises when I save it.

After saving the query the query automatically changes. I verified the db and the query there was ok. But the query was not rendering ok on the screen.

This is what my query looks like

[image]

and this is what it looks like after it gets rendered after being saved

[image]

why the issue is occurring?